# Sliding page transitions with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, transition, sliding

I am working on a simple project that displays some of a clients work in a full-screen style page. When I click a link, a project loads and displays at 100% width and height. I have a link to the previous and next project on the page, but I need the content to slide to the left when the 'next' button is clicked and the to the right when the 'previous' button is clicked. I have the transitions working and animating in the correct directions, but I'm not sure how to load in my new content(the next or previous project) via jquery ajax. My thoughts were to create "placeholder" containers on the left and right sides of the screen and load the content into those and slide it in from the left and right, but that feels a bit clunky to me. Any suggestions on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

What you suggests the correct way to do it, how else could you animate something in?